# Getting the value of a select element which is hidden in a multiple select element form

Tags: html

I am working on a form which have multiple select fields with multiple options. But only one select field is displayed while the other is hidden with `display: none`.

The issue right now is, I am getting the value for both the fields even though one is hidden.

Here's my two select input fields where only one is visible according to the user's choice.

```html
<select id="entry" name="entry">
        <option value="slide-in-center" >Center</option>
        <option value="slide-in-right">Right</option>
</select>

<select id="exit" name="exit" style="display: none;" >
        <option value="slide-out-center" >Center</option>
        <option value="slide-out-right">Right</option>
</select>
```

After the form is submitted I get output from both the fields. Like:

```
{
    entry: 'slide-in-center',
    exit: 'slide-out-center'
}
```

Why am I getting this? I had `selected` attribute in the first option for both. And I thought it is because of this so I removed this but it is giving out the same output. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `display: none` is just a style (css). styles are visual. form submit works by taking value from form elements inside `<form />`. it does not care if its visual, do to css, or not. css is JUST visual. To do that either a) filter out the submition in backend or b) make the form dynamic by not rendering the select

Comment: Thanks mate. I understood.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `select`, even with display set to `none` will still be submitted as part of the form. I believe it used to be enough to prevent it from being submitted, but it changed.

Adding the [`disabled` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/disabled) to your select will prevent it from being submitted with the form.

Answer (score 1):

the default value is the first option.  add a blank option

```js
var entry = document.getElementById('entry').value
console.log(entry)

var exit = document.getElementById('exit').value
console.log(exit)


var entry2 = document.getElementById('entry2').value
console.log(entry2)

var exit2 = document.getElementById('exit2').value
console.log(exit2)
```

```html
<select id="entry" name="entry">
        <option value="slide-in-center" >Center</option>
        <option value="slide-in-right">Right</option>
</select>

<select id="exit" name="exit" style="display: none;" >
        <option value="slide-out-center" >Center</option>
        <option value="slide-out-right">Right</option>
</select>


<select id="entry2" name="entry">
        <option value=''></option>
        <option value="slide-in-center" >Center</option>
        <option value="slide-in-right">Right</option>
</select>

<select id="exit2" name="exit" style="display: none;" >
        <option value=''></option>
        <option value="slide-out-center" >Center</option>
        <option value="slide-out-right">Right</option>
</select>
```